# Why 'YYModel' lead project crash on iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

My `YYModel` is managed by `cocoapods`. I use `YYModel` to convert json to model.There is my code where use YYModel:

```
for (NSDictionary *dic in labelArray) {
       CQMenuButtonModel *model = [[CQMenuButtonModel alloc]init];
       [model yy_modelSetWithDictionary:dic];
       [modelsArray addObject:model];
    }
```

It crashed at `[model yy_modelSetWithDictionary:dic];`,and the console showed:`'-[CQMenuButtonModel yy_modelSetWithDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18b47d20'`

However, it work fine on `iOS9` and `iOS10`.

At first I think maybe the newest YYModel doesn't fit `iOS8`, so I change the `YYModel's` version to 0.9, However,it's **crash** on `iOS8` too.

What confused me most is that why it crash on `iOS8` but work fine on iOS9 and iOS10,What's more,I really don't understand why console show me :`unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18b47d20`

Comment: Are you sure that `labelArray` is not being mutated while iterating through it?

Comment: @slashdot it's not mutated,`NSArray *labelArray = (NSArray *)[data objectForKey:@"label_list"];` Is there anything wrong?

Comment: @slashdot I change `labelArray` to `NSMutableArray`,it's crash,too.

Comment: Also you can check if all `dic` objects are really of type `NSDictionary`. And is `CQMenuButtonModel` an `NSObject`.

Comment: @slashdot But,I use `for (NSDictionary *dic in labelArray)`,can `dic` not a `NSDictionary `?In addition,I'm sure `CQMenuButtonModel `is a `NSObject `

Comment: Of course, it can. You can try the following code and see that it's crashing with unrecognized selector exception: `NSArray* array = @[@1, @"foo", @{ @2: @NO }];
    
    for (NSDictionary* dic in array) {
        NSLog(@"dic.count: %lu", (unsigned long)dic.count);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced YYModel with JSONModel at last then it work fine.